# What are the primary nutrients utilized by plants beyond NPK?

Tags: soil, fertilizer, nutrients

When talking about soil and fertilizers, what are the primary nutrients in addition to NPK (Nitrogen, Phosphorus, Potassium) that play a major role in plant development?

Comment: See the list of "Secondary Nutrients" here: http://www.seaofgreen.co.uk/advice/printed.asp?active_page_id=396

Answer (score 9):

Primary macronutrients are NPK as you mention.

From [this article on plant nutrients](http://www.ncagr.gov/cyber/kidswrld/plant/nutrient.htm):

> The secondary [macro]nutrients are calcium (Ca), magnesium (Mg), and sulfur (S).

and

> Micronutrients are those elements essential for plant growth which are needed in only very small (micro) quantities. The micronutrients are boron (B), copper (Cu), iron (Fe), chloride (Cl), manganese (Mn), molybdenum (Mo) and zinc (Zn).

Comment: Just wondering: is there a reasoning behind the naming convention of macro-/secondary/micro-nutrient?

Comment: "macro" = big, need larger amounts. "micro" = small, need smaller amounts? I've edited the quote to make it clearer that the "secondary" refers to macronutrients that are usually present in sufficient quantities.

Comment: (Sorry, I didn't mean for you to have to define macro/micro, I mean are the macro's used whole while micro's are combined or broken down or something along those lines)

Comment: No problem. They all have to be in forms that the plants can use directly. For example, there's **tons** of nitrogen in the air, but it's useless to plants. They need specific nitrogen-containing compounds to be present in the soil. The chemistry gets complex fast... I only know enough to be dangerous :)

Comment: And copper is a well known plant poison. ie. They only need a very tiny amount in the right form.

Comment: Indeed. Too much of any is not good. Excess potassium interferes with plants' ability to take up magnesium and/or calcium. See the table at the bottom of this page for the interactions that excesses cause: http://www.cartage.org.lb/en/themes/Sciences/BotanicalSciences/PlantHormones/EssentialPlant/EssentialPlant.htm